# Remove blocks of text by start and end keywoard notepad++ regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have data input file which looks like:

```
        Menu: textA
            Resource Id: 59517
            Picture File Name:
            Status Text:
            Menu Item Name:
.data CLASSPROPSSIZE
0000: 2400
.enddata
.data CLASSPROPS
0000: 4F004C0045005F00 4D0045004E005500 5F00470052004F00 550050000000FFFE
0020: 02000000
.enddata
                Resource Id: 45367
                Picture File Name:
                Enabled when:
                Status Text:
                Menu Item Name:
                Menu Item: TextB
.data CLASSPROPSSIZE
0000: 2400
.enddata
.data CLASSPROPS
0000: 4F004C0045005F00 4D0045004E005500 5F00470052004F00 550050000000FFFE
0020: 02000000
.enddata
```

I need to remove the whole .data and .enddata blocks with the .data and .enddata row too.

Unfortunately I was not able to write a regex which would remove all the unnecessary data blocks from the input data.

Comment: How far did you get with the regex that you were trying to write?

Comment: How can you describe the format of these blocks? What are the rules to match them?

Comment: Everything what starts with .data and ends with .enddata can be removed and everything in between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
\.data(?:(?!\.enddata)[\s\S])*\.enddata
```

Replace each match with a blank string.

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fJdldL/1)**

**Explanation:**

- `\.data` - matches `.data`
- `(?:(?!\.enddata)[\s\S])*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that does not start with `.enddata`
- `\.enddata` - matches `.enddata`

[image]